# Problem when trying to hide tab bar SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, padding, swiftui-tabview

There have been several questions like this one. There is a small difference which I didn't notice in any other answers. Basically I have a `TabView` and EACH of its items is wrapped inside `NavigationView`. Because it is done this way and not the other way around first `NavigationView` and than `TabView` the way to hide the view is not that simple.

```swift
extension UIView {
    func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        var allSubviews = subviews
        for subview in subviews {
            allSubviews.append(contentsOf: subview.allSubviews())
        }
        return allSubviews
    }
}

extension UITabBar {
    private static var originalY: Double?
    
    static public func changeTabBarState(shouldHide: Bool) {
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        windowScene?.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ view in
            if let tabBar = view as? UITabBar {
                if !tabBar.isHidden && shouldHide {
                    originalY = tabBar.frame.origin.y
                    tabBar.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 200
                } else if tabBar.isHidden && !shouldHide {
                    guard let originalY else {
                        return
                    }
                    tabBar.frame.origin.y = originalY
                }
                tabBar.isHidden = shouldHide
            }
        })
    }
}

struct MyTabView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var toggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView(toggle: $toggle)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Profile")
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var toggle: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(isActive: $toggle, destination: {
            Button("dismiss") {
                UITabBar.changeTabBarState(shouldHide: false)
                toggle.toggle()
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .onAppear {
                UITabBar.changeTabBarState(shouldHide: true)
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Click")
        })
    }
}

@main
struct AppTestingOne: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyTabView()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I get when doing this is the following. When I click the button at first screen I get sent here:

[image: Before Rotate]

On first look there doesn't seem to be a problem. In fact the button dismiss has like an invisible padding from the bottom. The interesting part is that when I rotate to landscape back to fullscreen, this padding disappears.

[image: After rotate]

When you look at these pictures there doesn't seem to be a problem, but when you have something at the top and at the bottom it gets pushed up and fixed when you re-rotate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a very cool solution. When I hide the tabBar I can push its superview down depending on the phone (formula needs to be calculated) and after rotation it continues to work just fine by ignoring by how much I have pushed it and going back to the way it should be which because I calculated it for iPhone 12,13,14 and it works just as fine.

```swift
extension UIView {
    func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        var allSubviews = subviews
        for subview in subviews {
            allSubviews.append(contentsOf: subview.allSubviews())
        }
        return allSubviews
    }
}

extension UITabBar {
    private static var originalY: Double?
    
    static public func changeTabBarState(shouldHide: Bool) {
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        windowScene?.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ view in
            if let tabBar = view as? UITabBar {
                if !tabBar.isHidden && shouldHide {
                    originalY = (tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y)!
                    tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y = (tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y)! + 4.5
                } else if tabBar.isHidden && !shouldHide {
                    guard let originalY else {
                        return
                    }
                    tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y = originalY
                }
                tabBar.isHidden = shouldHide
                tabBar.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
                tabBar.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        })
    }
}

struct MyTabView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var toggle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                RandomView(toggle: $toggle)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Profile")
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct RandomView: View {
    @Binding var toggle: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(isActive: $toggle, destination: {
            Button("dismiss") {
                UITabBar.changeTabBarState(shouldHide: false)
                toggle.toggle()
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .onAppear {
                UITabBar.changeTabBarState(shouldHide: true)
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Click")
        })
    }
}

@main
struct AppTestingTwo: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyTabView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're building for iOS 16, you can simply use

```
.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            FirstScreen()
            
            NavigationStack {
                Text("second")
                    .navigationTitle("second")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("second", systemImage: "2.circle")
            }
            NavigationStack {
                Text("third")
                    .navigationTitle("third")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("third", systemImage: "3.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstScreen: View {
    
    @State private var hideTabBar = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            VStack {
                Button("Toggle tab bar") {
                    withAnimation {
                        hideTabBar.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("first")
        }
        .toolbar(hideTabBar ? .hidden : .visible, for: .tabBar)
        .tabItem {
            Label("first", systemImage: "1.circle")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What if it is iOS 15?

Comment: nice solution, but only if you don't using navigation pushes. In this case you will facing with content jumps