# SwiftUI show tabbar again take current view's space

Tags: swiftui

I want to hide the tab bar in certain views and then show it again when returning to the Home view. However, when it reappears, the tab bar occupies some space at the bottom of my view. As far as I understand, the code to show the tab bar is executed after presenting the Home view. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

```
  Home.swift
    static var tabBar: UITabBar?
    VStack {
       ....
    }
    .onAppear {
       tabBar?.isHidden = false
    }

  Child.swift 
    static var tabBar: UITabBar?
    VStack {
       ....
    }
    .onAppear {
       tabBar?.isHidden = true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Share a reproducible code. Also I see that you are using `UITabBar` in SwiftUI. Is there any reason using UIKit element.

Answer (score 0):

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75450229/problem-when-trying-to-hide-tab-bar-swiftui) helped me solve this problem. I basically need to have control of superview by pushing it down

```
extension UIView {
    func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        var allSubviews = subviews
        for subview in subviews {
            allSubviews.append(contentsOf: subview.allSubviews())
        }
        return allSubviews
    }
}

extension UITabBar {
    private static var originalY: Double?
    
    static public func changeTabBarState(shouldHide: Bool) {
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        windowScene?.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.allSubviews().forEach({ view in
            if let tabBar = view as? UITabBar {
                if !tabBar.isHidden && shouldHide {
                    originalY = (tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y)!
                    tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y = (tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y)! + 4.5
                } else if tabBar.isHidden && !shouldHide {
                    guard let originalY else {
                        return
                    }
                    tabBar.superview?.frame.origin.y = originalY
                }
                tabBar.isHidden = shouldHide
                tabBar.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
                tabBar.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        })
    }
}
```